# How to split a String twice and automatically create a table (with n elements)?

Tags: java, loops, split

(Absolute beginner here)
My Goal is a table in which the elements in a separated array in one row are seperated by a comma and a new row after a space (" ").

A new row HAS to start after the space (meaning I can't replace it with let's say a dot).
I think my biggest problem is that I can't get "pretty 105" (notice the space) separated. It always counts as one element.

Right now the String only has 8 elements but you've to imagine the String being VERY long.

At first I want to split the String (including "pretty 105")

In the loop, I tried to make it to 'jump' after "pretty" because it should be splitting here

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

    String str = "104,Jeans,B&B,pretty 105,Shoes,Nike,nice";
    List<String> Row = Arrays.asList(str.split(" "));
    List<String> List = Arrays.asList(str.split(","));      


    StringBuilder buf = new StringBuilder();
    buf.append("<html>" +
               "<body>" +
               "<table>" +
               "<tr>" +
               "<th>Number</th>" +
               "<th>Name</th>" +
               "<th>Maker</th>" +
               "<th>Description</th>" +
               "</tr>");

    for (int j = 0; j < Row.size(); j++) {

        int i = j*4;

        for (; i < List.size(); i++) {              

          if (i<1+i) {
              buf.append("<tr><td>")
              .append(List.get(i))
              .append("</td>");
          }
          else if (i>=1+i) {
              buf.append("<td>") 
              .append(List.get(i))
              .append("</td>");
          }
          else if (i>3+i) {
              buf.append("<td>") 
              .append(List.get(i))
              .append("</td></tr>");
              break;
          }
    }
    }



    buf.append("</table>" +
               "</body>" +
               "</html>");
    String html = buf.toString();
    System.out.println(buf);}
```

In this example, the expected result is:

**Number** **Name** **Maker** **Description**

104,Jeans,B&B,pretty
105,Shoes,Nike,nice

But in the example above every one of them has its own line - except for "pretty 105":

104

Jeans

B&B

pretty 105

.
.
.

Comment: This looks more like Java than Javascript.

Comment: @apsillers you are right... the StringBuilder tricked me into thinking this is C#

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is that what you want ?

```
public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String str = "104,Jeans,B&B,pretty 105,Shoes,Nike,nice";
        final String join = String.join("\n", str.split(" "));
        System.out.println(join);
    }
}
```

EDIT:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

    String str = "104,Jeans,B&B,pretty 105,Shoes,Nike,nice";
    final String[] lines = str.split(" ");

    StringBuilder buf = new StringBuilder();
    buf.append("<html>" + "<body>" + "<table>" + "<tr>" + "<th>Number</th>" + "<th>Name</th>" + "<th>Maker</th>" + "<th>Description</th>" + "</tr>");

    for (String line : lines) {
        buf.append("<tr><td>")
                .append(line)
                .append("</td><td>");
    }
    buf.append("</table>" + "</body>" + "</html>");
    System.out.println(buf);
}
```

Comment: Pretty much. But one more thing: It NEEDs to be in that table. Can you tell me how to combine your line and my table (the loop dosen't matter)?

Comment: I don't really get the table thing.
Could you add the expected output ? if it's a file put the expected content.

Comment: I wanted to awnser your question but I have no idea how Comment formatting works so you'll have to imagine it ---- The name of the table is "buf" and I already prepared the headlines (Number, Name...) and below it are the corresponding contents. From my code you can see that I wanted to append newcoming data (from the string) to the table. It will be in HTML-Format.

Comment: Please see the edited solution, if the answer helped you, please don't forget to accept it.